# Имеется viewController в нем container viewController как передать переменную в контейнер

Tags: xcode, swift, apple, swift3

Имеется viewController в нем container viewController как передать переменную в контейнер который сразу парсит из апи данные 
Юзер дефаулт не работает
Переменная находиться в контейнере

Answer (score 1):

В IB указываете id для вашего segue, далее Вам необходим метод `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`.

Примерный код:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
 if segue.identifier == "YourSegueId" {
      if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? YourViewController {
            destinationVC.yourProperty = "Some value"
        }
   }
}
```

**Дополнение:**

Segue срабатывает при загрузке контейнера. Подробнее [тут](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/03/30/ios-container-view-pass-data/)